# Excute a sudo command inside a bash script with mutiple functions?

Tags: bash

In the script, I used **main** function to create a new sudo-bash to finish all the things with sudo.

```
#!/bin/bash
function sudo_stuffs() { 
  install_ss
}
function install_ss() {
  echo something
}



main() {
  # 切换目录
  cd /tmp 
  if [[ ! -d "install_shadowsocks" ]]; then
    mkdir install_shadowsocks
  fi
  cd install_shadowsocks

  # 如果没有sudo权限
  if ! sudo -v 1>/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    # 提示登录有权限的账户 
    echo "--- You don't have authority, login to the root or others in sudoers. ---"
    exit 1
  fi

  export -f install_ss
  FUNC=$(declare -f sudo_stuffs)
  sudo bash -c "$FUNC; sudo_stuffs"
}

main "$@"
```

But actually in the **sudo_stuffs** function, there are more detailed functions like 
**install_ss** function.

I even used `export -f install_ss` to make sure install_ss could be found in the sub shell called with `sudo bash -c "$FUNC; sudo_stuffs"`.

But still, the result came with

> bash: line 2: install_ss: command not found

what can I do please?

Comment: Maybe use `FUNC=$( declare f sudo_stuffs install_ss )`? Also, I would probably do `eval "$FUNC"` instead of using `$FUNC` unquoted.

Comment: Can you specify how you called the script, i.e. did you make it executable and then simply called `./scriptname.sh` or did you call it explicitly as a shell argument (like `bash scriptname.sh`)?

Comment: The point is, I am rather surprised the script generates any output at all, since bash scripts, as opposed to a compiled C program, don't have a 'default' _main_ function that is automatically executed. I would have believed that your script, actually shouldn't do anything because while you declare the function `main()`, you never call it inside the script.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yeah your code works.   But why `sudo -E` doesn't work? It can transfer string environment variables to the newborn shell if there is a `export a="1"` before the `sudo bash -c "$FUNC; sudo_stuffs"` line. But the `export -f install_ss` failed.

Comment: It fails because an exported function is not an ordinary environment variable. Even allowing ordinary environment variables to be passed via `sudo` is considered a security flaw by some, and it can be configured to be not allowed in the `sudoers` file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `function`, i.e. lines 2-4 would be:

```
sudo_stuffs() { 
  install_ss
}
```

Then to call it, just use:

```
sudo_stuffs
```

Finally, to get root permission when the user is not root, add these 3 lines to the beginning of your script (after line 1). This will run the script via `sudo`, which will check that the user has permission to run `sudo` and (normally) ask for a password :

```
if [ `id -u` -gt 0 ]; then
    exec sudo "$0" "$@"
fi
```

Comment: The point in this question is, I believe, to call the script as a non-privileged user and then have the script only use `sudo` for the things that actually require root permissions.

Comment: Okay - maybe I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I found a duplicate but according to the rule of StackExchange I can't set it.

So I publish it here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/57915/environment-variables-when-run-with-sudo

The real reason why command missing is `sudo` command discarded my environment variables which exported from my shell so the sub shell generated by sudo will not be able to know what is `install_ss` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your line  sudo bash -c "$FUNC; sudo_stuffs" looks wrong to me.
sudo -c should be followed by the commmand you wish to execute in quotes, end your quotes and then put the username you wish to execute the command as at the end.

```
sudo -c "bash FUNC sudo_stuffs" MY_USERNAME
```

allow im not sure if you can call a function in this way. I would usually call my function in the script and if you want the commands that make up your function to be run as a certain user you would add the suco -c "command" my_username to the function.

Comment: Note that `bash $FUNC` does not make sense with the expansion of `$FUNC` being a function definition.

Comment: Thanks, edited to give it a bit more relevance.